# birth date input not working after number 13 with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, input

We are doing AB testing. We can only touch the client side code with Google Optimize. So the designer asked us to change the birth date format from separated input to an unify input like this ->

[image]

So the idea is that the user type the birth date numbers `[13.07.1998]` and then the information will get to the separated input like this `[13] [July] [1998]`

It works fine until we use day 13. After that number the code does not work. But if I use 12 it works.

[image]

```
const dobInput = document.querySelector("input");
const birthDay = document.querySelector("#birthDay");
const birthMonth = document.querySelector("#birthMonth");
const birthYear = document.querySelector("#birthYear");

dobInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const dobString = e.target.value;

  if ( isValidDate(dobString) ) {

    let date = dobString.slice(0, 2);
    let month = dobString.slice(3, 5);
    let year = dobString.slice(6, 10);

    birthDay.value = date;
    birthMonth.value = month;
    birthYear.value = year;

  } else {

    const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".cro-error-text");
    errorMessage.classList.add('error');
    
  }
});

function isValidDate(dateString) {
  // First check for the pattern
  if (!/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/.test(dateString)) return false;

  // Parse the date parts to integers
  var parts = dateString.split(".");
  var day = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
  var month = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
  var year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

  // Check the ranges of month and year
  if (year < 1905 || year > 2004 || month == 0 || month > 12) return false;

  var monthLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  // Adjust for leap years
  if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0))
    monthLength[1] = 29;

  // Check the range of the day
  return day > 0 && day <= monthLength[month - 1];
}
```

Does anyone knows why it could be happening? thanks!

Comment: You have `parts[0]` and `parts[1]` interchanged when you're setting `day` and `month`. So when you type `13.01.1989` it thinks that `13` is the month, not the day.

Comment: Since `isValidDate()` already splits up the date string, why don't you have it return the parts so you don't have to split it up again in the event listener? And why don't you use the same `split()` method there?

Comment: You could also extract the parts with capture groups in the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you!!! you were right it was interchanged :) i changed back and now works!

Answer (score 0):

**I think the error is this....**

if-----------------------------------------

12 - - - 10 - - - 2000

Day - - - month - - - year

in your code you are saving

12 - - - - 10 - - - 2000

Month - - -Day - - - -year

---

---

I think the error is this because I think you are using selects tag.

select tags have options tag....and each option tag have a value.

```
<select>
<option value=1>Jenuary</option>
<option value=2>February</option>
</select>
```

So _select.value=13 is not posible.because there shouldn't be an

```
<option value=13>
```

### There is not a month 13...I think you are confusing month with day when you store it in the variable

---

**Or check if all options tags are within select tag...**

Comment: Thank you!!! you were right it was interchanged :) i changed back and now works!